# unable to show youtube video (link from mysql) in flutter

Tags: mysql, flutter, youtube

i am new to flutter development. i am creating app to show youtube videos by the link stored in mysql table using php.
everything is ok i am getting data from mysql table using php. but when i pass **link** parameter to youtube player, it shows error.

please tell me how to resolve problem of
**type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String'**

my code is here

````
  final String videoId;

  VideoPlayer({this.videoId});

  @override
  _VideoPlayerState createState() => _VideoPlayerState();
}
class _VideoPlayerState extends State<VideoPlayer> {
  var videoURL;
  YoutubePlayerController mYoutubePlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    videoURL = GetHelper.getVideo(widget.videoId, 'get_video', 'id');
    
    super.initState();
    mYoutubePlayerController = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(videoURL),
        flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(autoPlay: true, mute: false));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return YoutubePlayerBuilder(
      player: YoutubePlayer(controller: mYoutubePlayerController),
      builder: (context, player) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Youtube Video Player"),
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: player,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

 static Future getVideo(
      String dataId, String typeOfData, String inputData) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(global_var.baseurl+"/get_data/$typeOfData.php"),
          body: {
            "$inputData": dataId,
          });
      if (response.statusCode == 200) { // if every things are right
        var userData = await json.decode(response.body);
        // userData = userData[0]['cLink'];
        // print(userData);
        return userData;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

getVideo is  an async function you need to wait for the function to finish.since it would take some time to finish getting the result like this

```
videoURL =await  GetHelper.getVideo(widget.videoId, 'get_video', 'id');
```